# How to get signatures for the variable at point in tuareg-mode?

Tags: emacs, ocaml, tuareg

We can use `merlin` to do the auto-completion and the signature is displayed on the popup window; additionally we can use `Ctrl-h` or `?` to get additional defined variables in the module **during completion**.

But for *code reviewing*, how can I get these signatures? I tried `tuareg-list-functions` and a few others, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With merlin, `Ctrl-c Ctrl-t`. Please see [the merlin emacs manual](https://github.com/the-lambda-church/merlin/wiki/emacs-from-scratch#getting-the-types-of-expressions).